# Strong earthquake sensation in one's head, what could it be?

Tags: mental-health, neurology, thyroid

Patient is in early 70s, female, very healthy, but has a slight thyroid deficiency issue that is adequately treated with the relevant drugs.  Now, she occasionally (rarely) mentions that she experiences during the night very strong earthquake sensations.  The experience feels to her 100% real, and is really frightening.  She feels her bed shaking, etc...  She is typically asleep.  And, the event wakes her up in a state of anxiety.  But, no earthquake has occurred.  What could it be?  What should she investigate with her health care providers?

Comment: @CountIblis - Please do not answer in comments. If you are requesting clarification, make sure you are not offering a diagnosis.

Comment: R.Doto.  My understanding from talking with this person is that it is different or a lot more than what you suggest.  I personally have suffered from "exploding head syndrome" or whatever it is called.  This is a weird and benign disorder where you wake up in the middle of the night hearing a heart-stopping like bomb noise.  And, that's not just a nightmare thing.  This person experiences a similar thing, but instead of hearing a bomb, she feels like she is in the midst of a 7.0 earthquake.

Comment: Also, does the patient live in an area of frequent tectonic activity?

Comment: The person does live in the SF Bay Area.  But, she experiences the equivalent of violent tremors when none are recorded locally and roomates and neighbors present do not feel anything.  Also, about Hypnagogia... based on the description at Wikipedia, this is no better an explanation than someone stating that person has nightmares.  This is something very different.  The closest thing is think of the "exploding head syndrome" that I have experienced but instead of bombs think massive earthquake sensations.

Comment: @R.Doto - If you need three comments to say something, please put it in an answer, don't keep adding comments.

Comment: @johnp I was attempting to reach a broader peak of clarification. Why did you delete the comments? :/ I wasn't answering the question as, I needed to make sure I wasn't misunderstanding OP.

Comment: OP: You're better off submitting the question to Quora - they're less sensitive ;) Just add that, you suspect that it's 'Hypnagogia' in the description box to speed things up.

Comment: @R.Doto - I read through your comments again. There is no request to the OP for more information, it is a lot of explanation of hypnagogia. It would make a good answer if you wrote it as such.

Comment: @johnp Fair enough. The reason I provided the information was to avoid coming to an incorrect conclusion. OP was unsettled on the possibility that it could be sleep related so, I wanted to provide him with a stronger basis to agree on. Thus, depends on how you view clarification, I view it as an equal state of agreement that doesn't leave the patient in a state of confusion, achieved by limiting the possibility of being impartial. I didn't state that it was to request 'more information'.

Comment: @johnp  I was in fact going to write an answer to the question, I'm not up to it now. You could take the comments of mine, that you deleted, and use them to answer it yourself? I've provided you with most of the key medical information/perspective needed, the latter are widely available on the Web. It should be a case of filling in the blanks.